# Is there a flag or a way to know than an Account is a result of merged accounts?

Tags: soql, merge

In The AccountHistory I see an entry 'Account Merged'
However when I query the Account History Object to fetch a list of all Acocunts  which are a result of merge, I cannot see the Account Merged flag.

How can I fetch a list of Accounts that are the survivors of merged records?

Answer (score 2):

**MasterRecordId** field contains that value. This is from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_account.htm)

> If this object was deleted as the result of a merge, this field
> contains the ID of the record that was kept. If this object was
> deleted for any other reason, or has not been deleted, the value is
> null. This is a relationship field.

Answer (score 2):

@Himanshu's answer is what you're looking for if you're just needing an easy flag/field on account to denote it's been through a merge.

I did want to correct what you noted. The entry you see in the UI is, in fact, in the `AccountHistory` object and you can query that.

`Field` will be `accountMerged` and `OldValue` will contain the name of the account that was merged into your existing account.

```
SELECT Id,Field,OldValue,NewValue 
FROM AccountHistory 
WHERE Field = 'accountMerged'
```